# Getting certain part of string with delimiters

Tags: java, string, message, minecraft, delimiter

I'm using
`String message = event.message.getFormattedText();` to get the text of the message, and currently I change the Minecraft player's username with `message = message.replaceAll("(?i)" + Minecraft.getMinecraft().thePlayer.getName(), NameAndColorUtils.nickname);`. However, some messages are structured as such:

```
Title [RANK] Username: Message 


Rookie [VIP] Player: Hello!
```

I would like to be able to get both the delimiters "[" and "]", as well as the text in between and replace that with a string of my choosing. For example, changing [VIP] to [MVP], or to remove the rank entirely (depending on the user's input). How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex replacement loop, e.g. something like this:

```java
static String replace(String message) {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\[([^\\]]+)\\](\\s*)").matcher(message);
    while (m.find()) {
        String tag = m.group(1);
        if (tag.equals("RANK")) {
            // Remove tag and trailing space
            m.appendReplacement(buf, "");
        } else if (tag.equals("VIP")) {
            // Replace tag and keep trailing space
            m.appendReplacement(buf, "{MVP}" + m.group(2));
        }
        // No else clause means that text is left intact for unknown tags
    }
    return m.appendTail(buf).toString();
}
```

*Test*

```java
System.out.println(replace("Title [RANK] Username: Message"));
System.out.println(replace("Rookie [VIP] Player: Hello!"));
System.out.println(replace("Hello [FOO] World"));
```

*Output*

```
Title Username: Message
Rookie {MVP} Player: Hello!
Hello [FOO] World
```

Comment: Is there any way I'm able to get the tag directly from the user's message, and then replace it there? So for example, if a user send the message [MVP] Player: Hello! it could get the tag ONLY from the user's message and then replace the tag with [VIP]?

Comment: @Gungee Isn't that what this code is doing? Getting the tag *from the message* and then deciding what to do with it, e.g. replacing it with something else.